# Troubles with logging in with a newly created user

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I created a CRUD that allows me to create users, societies and schools in a back office.

However, for an unknown reason, I can't log in with a created user with the password I gave him.

Here is my controller (the part where the user is created)

```
/**
 * Creates a new User entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="user_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm('UserBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


        $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());

        $user->setPassword($password);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_show', array('id' => $user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

After registering a new user, when I check it in the fos_user table, I can see that the password has been encrypted. However, if I try to login with the password I used, I simply get "bad credential" from my login form.

I can't figure out why.
Tell me if you need to see another file, I'll update my question

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 $user->setPassword() updates password as plain text \[DataFixtures + FOSUserBundle\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183368/symfony2-user-setpassword-updates-password-as-plain-text-datafixtures-fos)

Comment: I don't want to populate my database, I want my admin to be able to create users with a simple register form... I tried the example in the cookbook but it still fails;.

Comment: ok, I'll answer it here then

Comment: Never mind, I found out that when I create a user, everything is fine excepted that the user account is disabled. I just had to add $user->setEnabled(true), and everything workrd fine!

Comment: if salt is empty in your database, then your site is vulnerable to bruteforce by encrypted vocabulary, so it's better to use UserManager and setPlainPassword.

Comment: i use Bcrypt to encode, I checked when I created these users and the salt column gets filled each time, so no problem there :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to create user and set password in FOSUserBundle is the following:

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

$userAdmin = $userManager->createUser();

$userAdmin->setUsername('System');
$userAdmin->setEmail('system@example.com');
$userAdmin->setPlainPassword('test');
$userAdmin->setEnabled(true);

$userManager->updateUser($userAdmin, true);
```

Password is kept encrypted in database. And to make it harder to bruteforce, database contains an additional field, named salt. You don't store it in your code, that's why it's impossible later to check password. But actually, you don't have to encrypt password and store it in database. User model contains a special method for it, setPlainPassword, which is intended to encrypt password populate both fields salt and password in database with correct values.