# CRUD,edit manually a user FOSUserBundle Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

i am trying to edit my user, and i get no errors when i submit, but the user is not updated in the DB.

i was wondering that, if the admin make some changes in the user(the other fields, not password), it will persist the user with the old password, and if the admin change password, it will persist the newest password :D

sorry for my english and thank you guys :)

this is my EditAction in \UserController.php

```
public function editAction(Request $request, User $user)
{                  
    $password = $user->getPassword();

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($user);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('UserBundle\Form\EditUserType', $user);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);


    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        if(!empty($form->get('password')->getData())){
            $user->setPlainPassword($form->get('password')->getData());
            }
        else{
        $user->setPassword($password);
            }              
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_edit', array('id' => $user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('UserBundle:user:edit.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

and this is my form \EditUserType.php

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('prenom')    
        ->add('username') 
        ->add('email')
        ->add('password', 'repeated',
        array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'Les mots de passes doivent être identique',
            'required' => false,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Nouveau mot de passe'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirmation du mot de passe')
        )
        )                
        ->add('enabled')
        ->add('last_login')
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FosUserBundle Manager service, according to this : [Fos User Manager Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183368/symfony2-user-setpassword-updates-password-as-plain-text-datafixtures-fos).

Comment: Have you got the time to test ?

Comment: Can you please tell us what is going ?